# PHP Базовая авторизация

Tags: php, http, аутентификация

Как заставить работать http-авторизацию? При выполнении данного кода и при вводе верных данных - все равно появляется окно авторизации в браузере

```
if (@$_COOKIE['sid'] != '33') { 
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == '33') {
        setcookie('sid', '33');
        header('Location: /');
    } else {
        die ("Not authorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень странно, у меня ваш код работает, если логин ввести `33`, а пароль оставить пустым.

Comment: у Вас какая версия php и какой браузер и какой версии используете?

Comment: Хром последний, PHP 5.6 OpenServer

Comment: На PHP 7.0 так же работает.

Comment: у меня на хроме, IE, Firefox такая-же беда. у меня хостинг на regru, пробовал менять версии php - не помогло

Comment: У вас .htaccess есть в корне сайта? Возможно в нём что-то? Попробуйте его полностью очистить и протестировать.